# django 'module' object has no attribute 'StringProperty'

Tags: python, django-models, attributeerror

I'm just starting... I'm trying to use Django models but I'm getting the:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StringProperty'

Can you please tell where can be the issue?

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Test(models.Model):
    text = models.StringProperty()
    date = models.DateTimeProperty()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you mixed it up with Google App Engine. They have their own model and field classes. `StringProperty` is the equivalent to `CharField` and `DateTimeProperty` the equivalent to `DateTimeField` in django.

Comment: Don't you people use search?  ["has no attribute" python](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22has+no+attribute%22+python)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you've got some bogus model field types. Here are the correct ones for django (read about them and other available field types in the [django model field reference docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/%20%22django%20model%20field%20reference%22%20docs))

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Test(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```